# Bootstrap Uno API LibreOffice exception

Tags: c#, exception, uno

With the following code:

```
static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        var context = uno.util.Bootstrap.bootstrap();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

I can start Writer of LibreOffice. This works fine with Version 4.4.4 but after installing version 5.0.0 and with new SDK `Bootstrap.bootstrap()` throws the exception:

`"External component has thrown an exception"`

Has anyone faced the same problem or some solution?
(.NET 4.0, Windows 7 64-bit, LibreOffice 5.0 Lite)

Comment: Is there any inner exception on the exception thrown that might contain more information, like *which* external component originated it?

Comment: Following is the exception

A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in cli_cppuhelper.dll
cppu.bootstrap(Reference<com::sun::star::uno::XComponentContext>*

Comment: This issue is referenced on [bug tracker](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94265). It confirms that adding `C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program` to environment variable "PATH" solves the issue for most people.

Answer (score 8):

I have managed to solve the problem by setting the `UNO_PATH` environment variable before starting the `soffice.exe` server:

```
using static System.Environment;

var unoPath = @"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program"
// when running 32-bit LibreOffice on a 64-bit system, the path will be in Program Files (x86)
// var unoPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program"

SetEnvironmentVariable("UNO_PATH", unoPath, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") + @";" + unoPath, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

This was required because LibreOffice 5's program directory does not have "URE" subdirectory anymore (previous versions did) which is required for UNO layer.

Comment: Thanks, but this solution not always work. I have tested under different Windows versions and on some it work and on some not.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I'm using it on Windows Server 2012 R2, works perfectly. Here is the code:
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("UNO_PATH", unoPath, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", 
  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") + 
  @";" + unoPath, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly, but only if I have libreoffice 32 bit, with libreoffice 64 bit I still got errors, any suggestion?

Comment: @Alkampfer Have you tried to use "Program Files" instead of "Program Files (x86)" for x64 version?

Answer (score 5):

To get the path to the LibreOffice installation you can ask e.g. the Windows registry. In C# this is smoething like that:

```
    String unoPath = "";
    // access 32bit registry entry for latest LibreOffice for Current User
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey hkcuView32 = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.CurrentUser, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView.Registry32);
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey hkcuUnoInstallPathKey = hkcuView32.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\LibreOffice\UNO\InstallPath", false);
    if (hkcuUnoInstallPathKey != null && hkcuUnoInstallPathKey.ValueCount > 0)
    {
        unoPath = (string)hkcuUnoInstallPathKey.GetValue(hkcuUnoInstallPathKey.GetValueNames()[hkcuUnoInstallPathKey.ValueCount - 1]);
    }
    else
    {
        // access 32bit registry entry for latest LibreOffice for Local Machine (All Users)
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey hklmView32 = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView.Registry32);
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey hklmUnoInstallPathKey = hklmView32.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\LibreOffice\UNO\InstallPath", false);
        if (hklmUnoInstallPathKey != null && hklmUnoInstallPathKey.ValueCount > 0)
        {
            unoPath = (string)hklmUnoInstallPathKey.GetValue(hklmUnoInstallPathKey.GetValueNames()[hklmUnoInstallPathKey.ValueCount - 1]);
        }
    }
```

Then you can use the answer of Funbit [ https://stackoverflow.com/a/31937114/2936206 ]

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way I found is just copy the URE folder from previous LibreOffice version to LibreOffice 5.