# Bootstrap Uno LibreOffice exception

Tags: c#-4.0, exception, libreoffice, uno

With the following code:

```
static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        var context = uno.util.Bootstrap.bootstrap();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

This code works fine in win 7 but getting "SEH Exception handled by user code External component has thrown an exception".

**Lastest Version**:Libreoffice 5.0.3.2..Please help me to resolve this problem immediately.

Comment: Do you have a complete stacktrace? Any instructions to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Uno API LibreOffice exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31856025/bootstrap-uno-api-libreoffice-exception)

Comment: See also https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94460

Answer (score 0):

Look the response of another topic:

[Bootstrap Uno API LibreOffice exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31856025/bootstrap-uno-api-libreoffice-exception)

`````
var unoPath = @"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program"
// when running 32-bit LibreOffice on a 64-bit system, the path will be in Program Files (x86)
// var unoPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program"

SetEnvironmentVariable("UNO_PATH", unoPath, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") + @";" + unoPath, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);````
`````