# VB.Net example for LibreOffice SDK

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, macros, libreoffice, uno

The [WriterDemo example](https://api.libreoffice.org/examples/CLI/VB.NET/WriterDemo/) uses VB.NET to interact with the UNO API.  (The files are also included with the [SDK](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/) download in `file:///C:/Program Files/LibreOffice 5/sdk/examples/CLI/VB.NET/WriterDemo/`.)

To build and run,  I set up the command line environment according to https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/install.html, and then executed the Makefile using `make WriterDemo.run`.  But it crashes on this line:

```
xContext = Bootstrap.bootstrap()
```

The error message:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.
   at cppu.bootstrap(Reference<com::sun::star::uno::XComponentContext>* )
   at uno.util.Bootstrap.bootstrap()
   at WriterDemo.Main()
make: *** [WriterDemo.run] Error -1066598274
```

This is a followup of the question [Equivalent of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel for Open Office and/or Libre Office for VB.NET/Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45277899/equivalent-of-microsoft-office-interop-excel-for-open-office-and-or-libre-office).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Visual Studio instead of the Makefile.

- Start a new Visual Basic Console Application.
- Paste the code from WriterDemo.vb into Module1.vb.  Rename Module1.vb to WriterDemo.vb by right-clicking on the file in Solution Explorer.
- In Project Properties, change Startup object to `WriterDemo`.
- Right-click on References and choose Add References.  Browse to the `cli` folder in the SDK, for example `C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\sdk\cli`.  (The files in the GAC did not work for me.)
- Select all 5 files from that folder and press Add.  Then be sure that there is a check mark in each of their boxes.
- Modify `App.config` to fix the loading problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604663/what-does-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-do-in-the-net-4-config).
- To avoid a warning, set the processor architecture to `x86` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113532/how-do-i-fix-the-visual-studio-compile-error-mismatch-between-processor-archit).
- It may also be necessary to [set UNO_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31856025/bootstrap-uno-api-libreoffice-exception/31937114#31937114), although it worked for me without doing this.

Now press `Start` in the toolbar (or Debug -> Start Debugging).  If all goes well, it will start LibreOffice and insert some content into Writer.

An older example describing VB 2005 is at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=21494.

Thanks to @Zev Spitz for hints and corrections.