# How to print a .ODT file in C # or VB.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, openoffice-writer

I have a program in VB.NET that opens and changes a document with ODT extension, I am using the AODL dll, below a trex of code:

```
Imports AODL.Document.TextDocuments

Dim document As New TextDocument
document.Load(PathLayout)
SearchAndReplaceString(document, "@NAME", "JOSÉ")
SearchAndReplaceString(document, "@LASTNAME", "HARTMANN")
document.SaveTo(PathLayout& nameArchive & ".odt")
document.Dispose()

 Public Sub SearchAndReplaceString(ByRef document As TextDocument, ByVal searchText As String, ByVal replaceText As String)
```

what can i do for print this document?

I tried the code below:

[image]

But, the objects is not recognized

Comment: Maybe show what you tried, what you looked at.

Comment: thanks @ChristianM , I've already improved my question

Answer (score 0):

The code from the image, apparently based on https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/AODL_example_17, uses `OpenOfficeLib.Connection`.  I could not find a good place to obtain this library, and it sounds like you may not have it either.

Instead, I recommend sticking to the standard `unoidl` library that comes with the LibreOffice SDK.  Here is an example of printing a document using VB.NET.  It was adapted from the `WriterDemo` example included with the SDK.

```
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports unoidl.com.sun.star.lang
Imports unoidl.com.sun.star.uno
Imports unoidl.com.sun.star.bridge
Imports unoidl.com.sun.star.view
Imports uno.util
Imports System.Environment
Module WriterDemo
    Sub Main()
        Dim unoPath As String = "C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program"
        SetEnvironmentVariable("UNO_PATH", unoPath, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)
        SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") + ";" + unoPath, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)
        Dim xContext As XComponentContext = Bootstrap.bootstrap()
        Dim xFactory As XMultiServiceFactory = DirectCast(xContext.getServiceManager(), XMultiServiceFactory)
        Dim xDesktop As unoidl.com.sun.star.frame.XDesktop
        xDesktop = DirectCast(xFactory.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop"), unoidl.com.sun.star.frame.XDesktop)
        Dim xComponentLoader As unoidl.com.sun.star.frame.XComponentLoader
        xComponentLoader = DirectCast(xDesktop, unoidl.com.sun.star.frame.XComponentLoader)
        Dim arProps() As unoidl.com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue = New unoidl.com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue() {}
        Dim xComponent As unoidl.com.sun.star.lang.XComponent
        xComponent = xComponentLoader.loadComponentFromURL("private:factory/swriter", "_blank", 0, arProps)
        Dim xTextDocument As unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument
        xTextDocument = DirectCast(xComponent, unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument)
        Dim xText As unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XText = xTextDocument.getText()
        Dim xSimpleText As unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XSimpleText
        xSimpleText = DirectCast(xText, unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XSimpleText)
        Dim xCursor As unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XTextCursor = xSimpleText.createTextCursor()
        xText.insertString(xCursor, "The first line in the newly created text document." & vbLf, False)
        Dim xPrintable As unoidl.com.sun.star.view.XPrintable
        xPrintable = DirectCast(xComponent, unoidl.com.sun.star.view.XPrintable)
        Dim printOpts() As unoidl.com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue = New unoidl.com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue() {}
        xPrintable.print(printOpts)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Instructions for running the code: [VB.Net example for LibreOffice SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45359041/vb-net-example-for-libreoffice-sdk).